# What Node Rss module handles authentication

Tags: node.js, rss, basic-authentication

I need to call an RSS feed using basic authentication. How best can I do this?

I tried [node-easyrss](https://github.com/drudge/node-easyrss), but the call doesn't have a parameter for authn.

```
var request = client.request('GET', address, {'host': parts.hostname});
```

Answer (score 0):

[FeedMe.js](https://github.com/fent/feedme.js) can parse RSS feeds, but you'll have to make the request yourself. Which means you can handle auth and all custom headers you'd like.

```
var http = require('http');
var FeedMe = require('feedme');

var options; // put authentication here
http.get(options, function(res) {
  if (res.statusCode !== 200) throw Error('not found');

  var feed = new FeedMe();
  res.pipe(feed);
  feed.on('item', function(item) {
    console.log(item);
  });

}).on('error', function(err) {
  throw err;
});
```